# Understanding geth output

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, solo-mining

Im trying to mine ETH on AWS for learning pourpouses folowwing [this](https://github.com/angelomilan/ethereum-guides/blob/master/GPU-cloud_mining.md) tutorial

After I ran these comands to install geth:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum-qt
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum-dev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ethereum
```

and ran "geth" (no arguments)

it is producing the output bellow - which is very different from the one on the tutorial (and other tutorials I've seen). 
Am I doing something wrong? If yes, what? If not, can you help me interpret the outut? 
The `~/.ethereum/geth$` folder is already 25Gb - I presume thats where the chain lives, right?

[image]

Comment: it is downloading the blockchain, wait for it to finish

Comment: thanks @Nulik. How do I know how much left? It doenst mention blocks anywhere. Thanks